# Sharing data on facebook using html php, code

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Open Grapgh** code in head.

```
    <head>
      <title>Sale Scrap</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta property="og:title" content="salescrap.online" />
      <meta property="og:image" content="www.salescrap.online/Image-Building/5a66f4a440a12building.gif">
      <meta property="og:description" content="Ads post by Name:Awais Phone Number:03016660717">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
```

Facebook sharing Button

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=www.salescrap.online/detail.php?Id=4&Type=Image-Building" 
     target="_blank"><strong style="color:#007bff;">Share On:</strong><img src="Image/Facebook.png" width="150px" height="50px">
```

this code not work proper and not get info. when i click on share button open in new tap and on facebook site not get picture and skip the last part like this -> **Type=Image-Building**  from this link http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=www.salescrap.online/detail.php?Id=4&Type=Image-Building and also not get info through `<og>` meta tag in WhatsApp.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.salescrap.online%2Fdetail.php%3FId%3D4%26Type%3DImage-Building

> Provided og:image URL, www.salescrap.online/Image-Building/5a66f4a440a12building.gif was not a valid URL

Add the protocol to your `og:image`:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.salescrap.online/Image-Building/5a66f4a440a12building.gif">
```